# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH/DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on macos

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables, zsh

On macos catalina 
'''echo $VARIABLE'''
[image]

I see the value of the variable but java couldn't read the system variable. 
[image]

In linux there is not a problem so I think it is a zsh issue.

Java read all the variables `env`, except **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** and **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**

Answer (score 10):

Variables LD_LIBRARY_PATH / DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH are not passed to the environment of a child process on macOS if System Integrity Protect (SIP) is enabled.

To confirm :

```
#!/bin/zsh

cat << EOF > EnvDemo.java
public class EnvDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println(System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"));
      System.out.println(System.getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"));
      System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
      System.out.println(System.getenv("CUSTOM_FLAG"));
   }
} 
EOF

javac EnvDemo.java
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/library
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/library
export CUSTOM_FLAG=custom_flag
java EnvDemo
# null
# null
# /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/oracle-19-5
# custom_flag

echo "env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# No output here
echo "env | grep DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
env | grep DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
# No output here
```

Comment: A little late. Faced the same issue and worked around it using symlinks. Check it out here: https://wissel.net/blog/2022/01/maven-jna-macos-and-ld_library_path.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that any given env variable in a process is not necessarily copied to any processes spawned from it.

So, here, your zsh process clearly has the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable, but your java process does not.

If you set it like so:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/blabla`

you'd get this behaviour. You're looking for:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/blabla`

Comment: Problems occur only the names LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. I try another names all other variable works without problem

Comment: Check your `java` executable (run `which java`). It could be a shell script that is setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running the real `java`.