# JUnit test works, but maven test fails due to library not found on macOS (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Tags: macos, maven, junit, lotus-notes, hcl-notes

I have a simple JUnit test that I successfully run inside Eclipse on macOS Mojave. The class makes a JNA call to a dynamic library, so I had to set the Runtime environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

When I try to run `mvn test` both inside or outsite of Eclipse, they fail.

The reason, so I learned, is macOS' [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) which [wipes all `DYLD` variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html). However it must be possible to set them, somehow, since the JUnit test inside Eclipse works as designed.

I tried to "hack" the `mvn` shell script which ar the very end executes:

```sh
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  $MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS \
  -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${MAVEN_HOME}" \
  "-Dlibrary.jansi.path=${MAVEN_HOME}/lib/jansi-native" \
  "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

by setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` immediately before the `exec` command, without success.
Also tried to patch `$JAVACMD` to set the variable first, no luck.

What options did I miss (short of disabling SIP)?

**I'm not looking for a general solution, running `mvn` is my goal**

Similar questions:

- [Why isn't DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH being propagated here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568122/why-isnt-dyld-library-path-being-propagated-here)
- [LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH not imported on OS X](https://github.com/nteract/nteract/issues/1523)
- [How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH/DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126159/how-to-set-ld-library-path-dyld-library-path-on-macos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't like it, but it seems to work. The JNA call went out to load additional code that uses the `@executable_path` annotation. Running Java, the executable is the JVM, not the original application and thus the JNA call would fail.

Linking the whole program directory (and cleaning up thereafter) did the trick for me. My call to `mvn` looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Ugly hack to make mvn play ball
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
for onelib in $(ls /Applications/HCL\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS)
do
    echo "Linking /Applications/HCL\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/${onelib}"
    sudo ln -s /Applications/HCL\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/${onelib} ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/bin/${onelib}
done
# Maven test    
mvn test
# Cleanup
sudo find $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete
```

YMMV