# Django error: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) python2.7 django project

Tags: django, python-2.7, sigabrt, abort

I'm facing a very strange error from few days now. I have a python2.7 project that was running smoothly but since few days its been throwing an error:

> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

I'm using virtual environment for my project. What happened was that few days ago I tried installing nginx using brew command and what I believe is brew updated some dependencies that were being used for python2.7 project (this is what i think might be the case). Now since that day, I'm facing this issue and I have googled it everywhere but couldn't resolve. Below is some information you might need to figure out.

my requirements.txt file

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.8.7
botocore==1.11.9
cachetools==3.1.0
certifi==2018.11.29
cffi==1.12.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.6.1
Django==1.6.5
django-appconf==0.6
django-autoslug==1.7.2
django-blog-zinnia==0.14.1
django-ckeditor-updated==4.4.4
django-common-helpers==0.6.1
django-compressor==1.4
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-cron==0.3.3
django-filter==0.15.3
django-hosts==0.6
django-htmlmin==0.11.0
django-imagekit==3.2.5
django-mobi==0.1.7
django-mobile==0.3.0
django-mptt==0.6.1
django-redis==4.4.0
django-sass-processor==0.2.6
django-simple-captcha==0.4.2
django-storages==1.1.8
django-tagging==0.3.2
django-xadmin==0.5.0
django-xmlrpc==0.1.5
djangorestframework==2.4.8
docutils==0.14
enum34==1.1.6
futures==3.2.0
google-api-core==1.7.0
google-auth==1.6.2
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.9.0
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.6
html5lib==1.0b8
httplib2==0.9
idna==2.8
ipaddress==1.0.22
jmespath==0.9.3
libsass==0.18.0
lxml==3.3.5
Markdown==2.6.7
MySQL-python==1.2.5
nginxparser==1.0.1
numpy==1.16.1
oauth2==1.5.211
oauthlib==3.0.1
pandas==0.24.1
pandas-gbq==0.9.0
pilkit==2.0
Pillow==5.3.0
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.4
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pydata-google-auth==0.1.2
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyparsing==2.0.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-twitter==1.3.1
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.13
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.1.13
simplejson==3.5.3
six==1.12.0
South==1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.6
ua-parser==0.8.0
urllib3==1.23
user-agents==1.1.0
uWSGI==2.0.15
```

When I try to run any kind of operation like schemamigration or anything then it throws an error

> Abort trap: 6

My OS version: Catalina v10.15.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your libraries are unsigned/old. Try this: https://dbaontap.com/2019/11/11/python-abort-trap-6-fix-after-catalina-update/

Comment: i have other environments running on python3 and other various projects as well...which are all running on latest environments and packages...do you think applying this solution would not effect them? Cuz I really dont want to mess things further :P

Comment: I honestly cannot tell you this. Ideally this should not even happen. Just like the article suggested upgrading packages should be first bet.

Are you on a virtualenv? Have you tried to recreate that or use the latest python2.7?

I personally use pyenv so I can have multiple versions of python and poetry with settings to create local venv in project directory. These two keep my machine separated from system python.

Comment: Amit, your reference helped me out. And yes I am using pyenv and my case is also same, all the packages are separated according to the needs. But Im guessing while installing nginx, it updated some dependencies on system level and i only didn't create a symlink in /usr/local/bin folder...i did it now and everything's running smooth. Thanks again mate!

Comment: Pleasure. There is another trick in case you need it.

Most Unixes have LD_LIBRARY_PATH or their equivalents that you can set for your environment for that application. It can load external libraries before system just like your path and can be used for only that application.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126159/how-to-set-ld-library-path-dyld-library-path-on-macos